# How to create average (decimal) based star rating in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have created star rating functionality which works fine for whole integers. But I would like to modify it and implement average star rating functionality. Functionality that is based on decimal points. In the below code, it takes 'Selected' props value as 2.5 but  How can I show half selected star as per decimal value (like 2.5, 3.4, 2.3 .. etc)?

Here is the code:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import './style.scss'

const Star = ({ selected = false, onClick = f => f }) => {
  console.log("selected : ", selected);

  return (
    <div className={selected ? "store-card-rating selected" : "store-card-rating"} onClick={onClick} ><i className="fas fa-star empty-star"/></div>
  );
};

Star.propTypes = {
    selected: PropTypes.bool,
    onClick: PropTypes.func
  };
  
  class StarRating extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { starsSelected :this.props.Selected};
      this.change = this.change.bind(this);
    }
  
    change(starsSelected) {
      this.setState({ starsSelected: starsSelected });
    }
  
    render() {
      const { totalStars } = this.props;
      const { starsSelected } = this.state;
  
      return (
        <div className="star-rating">
          {[...Array(totalStars)].map((n, i) => (
            <Star
              key={i}
              selected={i < starsSelected}
              onClick={() => this.change(i + 1)}
            />
          ))}
          <p>
            {starsSelected} of {totalStars} stars
          </p>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  StarRating.propTypes = {
    totalStars: PropTypes.number
  };
  
  StarRating.defaultProps = {
    totalStars: 5
  };

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StarRating totalStars={5} Selected={2} />, rootElement);
```

Comment: It depends if your Star component lets you draw half of a star or not.

Answer (score 1):

## **Solution 1**

There is a great package called [`react-rating`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-rating) that has exactly what you want, based on FontAwesome icons.

## **Solution 2**

Assuming you can, you could design .1 to .9 parts of the right part of your stars, and display it on your already displayed full star in grey for example. It could look somewhat like this (with hearts):
[image: .2 of a heart][image: .9 of a heart]